# I can't find a Google Script I created (that is not attached to a spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having trouble finding a saved script. I followed [this post](http://www.johneday.com/422/time-based-gmail-filters-with-google-apps-script) to create a script that schedules email deletion, and I believe I saved it, but searched for it in Drive to no avail. The script is still running because emails are being deleted.

**Things I've tried**

I've read other posts that mention tracking down the spreadsheet that a script is attached to, but I didn't create a spreadsheet (unless scripts are all mysteriously attached to a spreadsheet).

I searched Drive.

I attempted to visit script.google.com while signed into my account. It said that I need permission and that I need to ask the owner for access. This is a work account managed by Google Apps. I asked my admin and he can't access script.google.com either. The only thing I can think of that's worth mentioning is that we changed domains at one point, but I can't see how that would affect ownership or permission.

So, two questions really:

1. Where is the script?
2. Who is the owner of the account?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A possible alternative could be to search drive via the drive API though (ironically), Apps Script and see what turns up.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I looked, but nothing here either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it helps but you can try by accessing this link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=type:script

Also if you have a google apps account recheck with the admin if he has given you access.

Recheck your permissions at:
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

In there you can try to find the script if you ever ran it using your account.

Also might worth to take a look into this dev article:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#authorization_lifecycle_for_add-ons

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did search by script type; that didn't work, BUT checking apps permissions revealed the app: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwnt4n8hasnfbvu/screenshot.png?dl=0. How do I access it?

Comment: I also looked at that last article and checked the Google Dev Console, but there are no projects listed there.

Comment: Hi Tracy, seems that it is going to be difficult or impossible to recover that file. As you have the tutorial you can do it again and we will be happy to help you if you find any difficulties.

Comment: I FOUND IT! So based on your recommendation to check apps permissions (and my incredibly slow sleuthing skills), today I noticed the date the app was authorized. I went to Drive, scrolled through my past activity to the date (last year), and found a link to the file. I also found an item in the activity feed that showed me trashing the script (by accident) the next day. So, the script continued to run from my Trash folder and the Trash folder was never emptied. THANK YOU for your help!

Comment: No worries, happy that everything was sorted!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try visiting the Google Dashbboard at:
https://script.google.com/home/

This is another link to try in Google Drive, which will find all files in your Drive of type script, and restrict to those owned by you. 
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=type:script%20owner:me